# How do i get the recent inserted document in MongoDB with all it's fields?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm working on this REST application in python `Flask` and a driver called `pymongo`. But if someone knows `mongodb` well he/she maybe able to answer my question.

Suppose Im inserting a new document in a collection say `students`. I want to get the whole inserted document as soon as the document is saved in the collection. Here is what i've tried so far.

```py
res = db.students.insert_one({
                "name": args["name"],
                "surname": args["surname"],
                "student_number": args["student_number"],
                "course": args["course"],
                "mark": args["mark"]
})
```

If i call:

```
print(res.inserted_id) ## i get the id
```

How can i get something like:

```json
{
   "name": "student1",
   "surname": "surname1",
   "mark": 78,
   "course": "ML",
   "student_number": 2
}
```

from the `res` object. Because if i print `res` i am getting `<pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x00000203F96DCA80>`

Comment: So you are wanting to return the exact same value as you inserted. Why not save the data input to a variable then print/use it as you need? Otherwise you can `find_one` with the resulting `inserted_id`.

Comment: I agree with Alexander. I think that the most efficient way is to: save the data input to a variable, save the data input to MongoDB, wait for the ID, and if you get valid ID so you know that the object saved in the DB, so you can return safely the variable that contains the data input.

Comment: I can do that, but that's not i want because it doesn't have an `id` i want the one which comes with an id

Comment: Generate the _id on the client side, then you'll have the complete document as it would be stored.

Comment: Or save the data to a variable, then add the `id`/`_id` using `res.inserted_id` and return that merged value. This is simply limitation of `py_mongo`, there isn't an option to return the inserted document for `insert_one`. Either create a new merged value using the result or do an additional query using the `res.inserted_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the data to be inserted into a dictionary variable; on insert, the variable will have the `_id` added by pymongo.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

doc = {
    "name": "name"
}

db.students.insert_one(doc)

print(doc)
```

prints:

```
{'name': 'name', '_id': ObjectId('60ce419c205a661d9f80ba23')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the commenters are correct. The PyMongo pattern doesn't specifically allow for what you are asking. You are expected to just use the inserted_id from the [result](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult) and if you needed to get the full object  from the collection later do a regular [query operation afterwards](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one)